# Is it possible to export fbx files during runtime in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, export, fbx

I want to select a group of fbx files and export them as a new fbx file during runtime, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, but the package is still in preview https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.formats.fbx@2.0/manual/index.html

Comment: @DigvijaysinhGohil so I should run through all the fbx files and read their binaries and then write them to a new fbx file, Is that how it works?

Comment: I have not used the package personally, but the Doc's developer guide should get you going